# Use drive root as OneDrive folder

Tags: onedrive

When it comes to "change OneDrive Location" with the OneDrive Desktop application, we are not able to choose the whole drive as the principal folder.

Example: if we choose "F:" as the OneDrive folder, the application converts it automatically to "F:\OneDrive".

Is there a way to use the whole "F:" as the principal folder?

Comment: Can’t check it now, but you could probably add an *additional* mountpoint for that volume. It’ll be folder mountpoint, so it might just work.

Comment: Any tutorial how to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried using ``f:\`` instead of `f:`?

Comment: Yeah, same result. In fact, the Software add automatically "\OneDrive" to any folder you choose, even if it is a drive root. Example, if you choose "F:\mydata", it will convert it to "F:\mydata\OneDrive"

Comment: It seems to be the default behavior that OneDrive app will create a OneDrive folder for saving synced folders and files.